# FileNotFoundException/MissingMethodException when running XUnit tests under OpenCover

Tags: xunit.net, opencover

If I run my tests with this:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"xunit.console.exe" -targetargs:"\"test1.dll\" \"test2\" -noshadow -noappdomain -xml \"xunit-test-results.xml\"" -filter:"-[XUnit]* -[Moq]*" -skipautoprops -register:path64 -output:"opencover-report.xml" -log:All
```

I get lots of `FileNotFoundExceptions` loading dependencies and `MissingMethodException` running tests.

If I remove `-noappdomain` from the invocation of `xunit.console.exe` I get no erros but this result from `OpenCover.Console.exe`:

```
Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
    1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
    output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
    2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
    guide and the -register switch.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The coverage part was due to the lack of `+[*]*` in the filters.

The errors are probably the reason why `xunit.console.exe` uses `AppDomain`s by default.